# Web UI Components for dashboard on MVC and IE6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-6

As part of the next project I'm working on, the customer has asked for a user-customisable dashboard-style web page where they can place multiple different chart controls populated with various bits of data.

There are tons of libraries out there that allow you to do this kind of thing but most do not support IE6. (it's out of my hands, we have to target IE6. I know, pity me)

I've had great difficulty finding any appropriate 3rd party control libraries that will work on IE6 and are still supported so any recommendations would be welcome.

The rest of this app is ASP.NET (3.5) but we are wanting to make the dashboard section MVC so either native ASP.NET or MVC components would be fine but MVC would be preferable.

Comment: IE6? Yes, indeed I pity you. You might want to mention to your evil overlord that the last vestiges of support for IE6 (and WinXP) will be withdrawn in a little over a year, after which any remaining security holes will go unpatched. If they're comfortable with that risk then it's their problem, but make sure they're aware of it, because you can bet your life that there are hundreds of hackers out there just waiting for the day. Anyone still using IE6/WinXP when they go officially End Of Life will be hacked wide open within days: it's a racing certainty.

Comment: Yes, our customer is moving to IE8, but to say it's a slow process is an understatement. Unfortunately, we have no way at all to speed up that process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jqChart](http://www.jqchart.com/) supports IE6. It has version for ASP.NET MVC - http://www.jqchart.com/SamplesAspNetMVC

Comment: Thanks will take a look at that as well

Answer (score 2):

By far the best IE6-compatible library for charts is [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) and its sister library [g.Raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/). The main library is a general graphics library; the sister lib is for graphs and charts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Raphael does look good, though it's slightly lower level than I'd like.